# Stuck on Bootlogo After Upgrading to iOS 8.1 can't enter recover/dfu mode

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios

I upgraded my iPhone to iOS 8.1 with iTunes, after the update my iPhone 5 is stuck at apple boot logo. I tried to enter into the DFU Mode but the screen still stuck on apple logo. I also tried to enter recovery mode but i couldn't.

How can I unbrick my iPhone ?

**P.S** *My Sleep button is not working*

Comment: My iPad is such on something i haven't seen before. It's showing the iTunes logo and a picture of the plug.

Comment: Ok...I'm not thinking. Clearly the logo i described wants me to plug my device into a computer and launch iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Well a sleep button would be nice but without it I don't think there is a way of fixing it. Does it show up in iTunes? I guess not. Just go to an apple store and let them fix it. (And if you don't have AppleCare that should not matter since it is clearly their fault)

(Sorry I can't comment, too few reputation yet :/ )